# How to remove hard to delete files, automatically created after an update?

Tags: terminal, finder, x11

After an OS update you sometimes discover left-overs on your desktop, often named *(Previously) Relocated Items*. In my current case this was just an alias to **X11R6** nested in several folders: */Previously Relocated Items/Security/usr*.

I moved the folders and the contained forward to the trash but couldn't empty it: "X11R6 can't be modified or deleted". Annoying, why would you protect a simple forward in such a way? This is what *ls* tells me about the file: *lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     8B 13 Mar  2020 X11R6@ -> /opt/X11*.

Next, I try with Terminal but that also fails. *sudo rm -f* is rejected with "Operation not permitted".

What to do?

Comment: what if you hold OPTION while emptying the trash?

Comment: No effect. I saw that suggested on advice pages but it doesn't work here. Apparently, the file settings are even more restrictive, overly so, I would say, than for other undeletable files.

Comment: Please see if this works for you: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251603414?answerId=253111653022#253111653022